# Unity Editor Memory Leak

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, unity-editor

I'm working in unity3d and I've recently come across an issue that is extremely puzzling (and really a project stopper). Basically, When I press play in the editor, and then press stop, unity eats up a bit of my memory, and refuses to give it back (I discovered this when my mac kept running out of memory). In my main project, it eats about half a gig on every iteration (Obviously a real problem). I started removing code and objects from my project, to no avail. Eventually I just started a new empty project (even removing the camera and the light), and lo and behold, same problem. Not half a gig (more on the order 20 meg), but still a leak. I don't know what this could be. Here are some facts to note:

- I recently upgraded to Unity 2017
- I'm working on a macbook pro with 16 GB memory
- In the activity monitor, the total memory used goes up on every iteration of play/stop, but the Unity process memory does not. In fact, I can't find the process using the extra memory.
- I frequently have multiple instances of Unity running, and communicating with each other via UNET. However, the empty project running with no other instances open still leaked.
- When I put the computer to sleep, one of two things will happen: either a unity instance will crash, or a significant amount of memory will be freed up (approximately half of the memory eaten up by starting and stopping unity)

Does anybody have any idea what this could be? Has anyone experienced something similar? If this is a Unity bug how would I go about informing the correct people / avoiding the problem? If I did something wrong, what should I change?

Comment: I think the best would be reporting that bug at : https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/ Your post is great so you can copy/paste it i guess, maybe just add some screenshots. Once it's done, you should also post a new thread in the unity forums. If a moderator hear about this problem you'll maybe have an explanation or a faster bugfix.